# Magento 2.3 New product detail tabs prevent automatic nesting

Tags: magento2.3

In my layout file I created 2 new tabs. Both tabs appear, however one is nested below the other. I don't understand why Magento would do this behavior since I did not set any code that should trigger it. I actually cannot figure out how to stop it from doing it. See example

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="installationcaretab" template="product/view/installation_care.phtml" group="detailed_info">
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Installation and Care</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="warrantytab" template="product/view/warranty.phtml" group="detailed_info">
         <arguments>
            <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Warranty</argument>
         </arguments>
      </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My problem is caused by a customization done to the template where the blocks are called/displayed. Not a real issue.